# asynchronous serial transmission C

Tags: c, serial-port, posix, termios

So i'm working on a program, wich is vaguely going to resemble
[Br@y's Terminal](http://sites.google.com/site/braypp/terminal), but running from the commandline in linux

It will do asynchronous transmission, out the serial (Com) port.
Now i think the Header/library i need for this is the termios.h

Now i've only used posix a little before and i;m finding it rather heavy going digging though manpages/specifactions
http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/termios.h.html\

Does anyone know of any good guides to termios?
I would google it myself (i've tired) but i don't understand the content enough to know if a guide is good.
Am i using the right library,even?

Comment: hmm, is it worth changing to C++ for libserial.
I bet it is.
hen i cna use nice things like cin>
on the other hand i'm going to revert to thinking in OO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a wiki book available that covers [termios](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios). Yes you are using the right library. It's the only way to manipulate the device to talk over the serial line as it controls it. There is a brief introduction to [termios](http://blog.nelhage.com/archives/27) in this blog. Here is another wiki book on serial programming under [Linux](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: cool, I had come across the first wikibook, but the rest in new, thanks